# Accessing JAX-WS Published Endpoint is Not Working

Tags: java, web, service, jax-ws, endpoint

I am trying to create a *Web* *service* using *JAX-WS*. I do have a very basic Java project with the following:

**EmployeeService .java**

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class EmployeeService {

    @WebMethod
    public String getEmployee(String id) {
        return "Vlad Danila";
    }
}
```

**Exporter.java**

```
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

import services.EmployeeService;

public class Exporter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/hello", 
                new EmployeeService());
        System.out.println("Successfull!");
    }
}
```

Running the above will throw **no** error and print "Successfull!".

However, accessing *http://localhost:8080/hello* on browser gives *This page isn’t working*.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did an example with your code, and it works.. you have to add this to the browser to see

http://localhost:9999/ws/hello?wsdl

This is the url on my case. Then consume it with soap ui or another ws client.
The error you see its cause you are doing a get request on that url  and not a soap request.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give much context about what you are doing. JAX-WS is supposed to run in container. Do you run in container which is JEE compatible. See this tutorial, especially the last part:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html#gjyge

If you want something simple, I would recommend to make a spring-boot app, which will work out of the box for you. Forget about heavy JEE containers and try to run a simple spring-boot app which have integrated server inside the spring-boot app.

Here is a link to follow: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/